# Would this be good or bad, to multiply filesystem with 0,1?

Tags: hard-drive

The idea is about to increase the capacity of hard-disk or else storage devices. When filesystem would be multiplied with 0,1 then e.g. a hard-disk with 1 TB would have the capacity of 10 TB instead. The question is, if this is good for hardware or if this would be rather a stress-test for hardware?

Comment: *"filesystem would be multiplied with 0,1"* how, exactly?

Comment: You mean compression? This is a trade-off between storage and CPU usage. And many files cannot be compressed because they already are (photos, movies, ...).

Comment: @steeldriver - the idea is easy, but I see now, that source code for filesystem ext4 is more complex. Here I mean 0,1 is factor for to create a more smaller file-system which takes less space away from hard-disk. The thing is, that I dont know if this would be good for read-and-write heads of hard-disk. The source code of ext4 is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/ext4.h

Comment: @muclux - it is not compression like compression of files with tar.gz - it is the idea of a smaller file-system which needs less space. Multiplied with 0,1 it would be ten times smaller on the hard-disk.

Comment: @steeldriver - a little hack in gparted worked, where I had chosen 'ext4' - and then put into label the factor like this : *.(0.1);